# Subscribing to Application_BeginRequest

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to subscribe to the HttpApplication's BeginRequest event from Global.asax?

What I want to do is add a line of code to the Application_Start method of Global.asax which will then subscribe an object I have to the BeginRequest and EndRequest methods.

I know this can be done through HttpModules, but I can't use HttpModules for various reasons that I will not go in to.

The aim is to be able to add the same line of code to multiple websites' global.asax pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some more digging, and have found out that the Init method is the way to go for me. I'm not convinved that the Global.asax constructor or the Application_Start method are the way to go. According to the MS docs:

> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set any instance data because it will be available only to the first instance of the HttpApplication class that is created.

I'm interpreting that as: "Don't register an event here because it won't be available after the first request."

> The Init method is called once for every instance of the HttpApplication class after all modules have been created.

I'm interpreting that as: "Register your event here, because it will be registered for every new instance of the application, and the handler will not be dropped".

The key here is "after all modules have been created". The constructor is called before this, so won't be the right place. As for Application_Start, I've tried many times, but I cannot get the event registration to stick - which is proven by the docs.

So I tried adding the code to the Init method and it worked just fine
i.e.

```
public void Init()
{
    this.BeginRequest += attach your handler here;
    this.EndRequest += attach your other handler here;
}
```

Comment: In your Init function, where does the `sender` variable come from ?

Comment: @billy, I fixed the post, I must have made some or other copy-paste error

Answer (score 2):

I have

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Put your code here
End Sub
```

in Global.asax.vb (`Class [Global]`) and it works.

However, you need to call the method of some other class. To achieve this is necessary to add handler for `BeginRequest' in`GlobalNew`.

Example:

The Class:

```
Public Class MyHandlers
  Public Shared Sub MyCode(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path)
  End Sub

 End Class
```

Global.asax.vb:

```
Public Class Global_asax
   Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

   Public Sub New()
     MyBase.New()
     AddHandler Me.BeginRequest, AddressOf MyHandlers.MyCode
   End Sub

 Rem ....

 End Class
```

Comment: I put the code in the place you suggested, but for some reason my events never get fired.

Comment: I have created new ASP.NET Application project (visual basic), opened Global.asax.vb, found `Sub Application_BeginRequest`, put a breakpoint inside and run. The breakpoint have been hit. Can you try it?

Comment: The Application_BeginRequest gets fired, thats not the issue. The issue is that I can't fire code from another class when Application_BeginRequest is called without putting the code in there.

The point is that I don't want to copy my code into Application_BeginRequest

Comment: I have modified my response. I hope that now it is what you need.

Comment: Ok, so you're adding code to the constructor of Global.asax. I don't know what the implications are of doing this, but it seems like it would work. Thanks for that

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void Application_Start( object sender, EventArgs e )
 {
     HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

     app.BeginRequest += attach your handler here;
     app.EndRequest += attach your other handler here;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, but as stated, my code doesn't get executed. I need to do some more digging, but thanks

Comment: I have a class with an Init method which takes HttpApplication as a parameter. In the Init method it does the:
> BeginRequest += and 
> EndRequest += code
Module) which redirects to methods in the class. When i create a new instance of the class in the Application_Start of Global.asax and call Init, it does the hooking up, but I don't think the hooking up is successful because the delegates are never called. IvanH has an answer, but I'm not convinced that putting things in the Gloal.asax is safe...

Comment: Same experience for me. The method does not get executed.